# Select record between two column from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched on Google but didn't find any solution. Please, anyone help me out.

Problem:

I have three columns: `ID`, `Value1` and`Value2`in the `Datatable`.

`DataTable` looks like this :

```
ID   Value1   Value2
1      10       20
2      15       30
```

I want to find the data between a certain range. Let me clarify by showing an example:

*If I enter the value 15 to 30, it should not allow it, because 15 is already present between 10 to 20.*

This is the code I have written, if I enter the same value again then I will get the message:

```
bool inRange = dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(row => Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value1"]) == row.Field<Int32>("Value1")
             && Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value2"]) == row.Field<Int32>("Value2"));
if (inRange)
{
    //msg
}
```

So, how do I write the code to achieve my task as I have explained above?

Comment: What means "if i enter 15 to 30"? User input of two numbers? Where are these two variables in your query? Is `drCurrentRow` another DataRow? Do you want to compare two DataTables? Not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `==` with `>=` and `<=`:

```
if (dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row =>
      (
      Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value1"]) <= row.Field<Int32>("Value1") && 
      Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value2"]) >= row.Field<Int32>("Value1")
      ) 
      ||
      ( 
      Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value1"]) <= row.Field<Int32>("Value2") && 
      Convert.ToInt32(drCurrentRow["Value2"]) >= row.Field<Int32>("Value2")
      ) 
   )
  {
   //  value1 or value2 falls within an already existing range 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use a simple loop to check if the given values are presented in existing rows. It is something like;

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(row["Value1"]);
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(row["Value2"]);

            if (someValue>=val1 && someValue<=val2)
            {
                // do not insert
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Really you people are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `DataRow` with two values v1  and v2 and you want to look if a `DataTable` already contains rows where `row.Value1 <= v1` and `row.Value2 > v1` or `row.Value1 < v2` and `row.Value2 >= v2`?

```
int v1 = row.Field<int>("Value1");
int v2 = row.Field<int>("Value2");

var inRangeRows = from r in dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable() 
                  where (r.Field<Int32>("Value1") <= v1 && r.Field<Int32>("Value2") >  v1)
                     || (r.Field<Int32>("Value1") <  v2 && r.Field<Int32>("Value2") >= v2)
                  select r;

bool inRange = inRangeRows.Any();
```